Show a counterexample to the converse of the Intermediate Value Theorem
Consider the function $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ defined by
$$\begin{cases}f(x) = x \text{ for } x\in \mathbb{Q}\\ f(x) = 1 − x \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$ Prove for any $y ∈ [0, 1]$, there exists $z ∈ [0, 1]$ such that $f(z) = y$.
My idea was to use a cardinality argument. Obviously the rationals map to the rationals on the interval [0, 1] as a bijection. It remains to show that the irrationals are mapped bijectively. Suppose there exists a y ∈ [0, 1] s.t f(z) ≠ y, for all z ∈ [0, 1]. Then, since there are the same amount of irrationals in both the domain and codomain, two of the irrationals in the domain map to the same number in the codomain. This cannot be true because f is injective, so we conclude that there does exist a z that maps to y.
Is my argument valid? I am a beginner in proofs and real analysis, so please excuse any naive/silly thoughts. Also, if you can think of a more rigorous pf, please share in the comments! Tia

Does this answer your question? inverse of a rational / irrational defined function The function is not the same but the main argument is.

You have a function that is continuous only at $x=\frac12$. But you don't need such an extreme counterexample to disprove the converse of the IVT, do you?

Unfortunately, the argument is not valid, because there are infinitely many irrational numbers. Abstracting a little bit away from your argument, you are saying "if this function $f \colon S \to S$ is not surjective - if it misses an element of $S$ - then because there are $|S|$ inputs and only $|S|-1$ outputs, two inputs must go to the same output". That argument is only valid when $S$ is a finite set!
In fact, when $S$ is an infinite set, we can find functions $S \to S$ that are injective, but not surjective:

The standard example is to let $S = \mathbb N$ and let $f(n) = n+1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. This is an injective function, but it is not surjective: there is no $n \in \mathbb N$ for which $f(n)$ is the smallest natural number.
For a more relevant example, let $S$ be the set of irrational numbers in $[0,1]$, but define $f$ differently from what happens in the problem. Let $f(\frac12\sqrt2) = \frac13\sqrt2$, $f(\frac13\sqrt2) = \frac14\sqrt2$, and in general $f(\frac1n\sqrt2) = \frac1{n+1}\sqrt2$; for all irrational numbers $x$ not of this form, let $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is not surjective, because there is no $x$ for which $f(x) = \frac12\sqrt2$. However, this does not result in two irrational inputs mapping to the same output!

So now we see that the argument in the question does not work. What does work? Well, here's a different approach. (We're back to the function $f$ defined in the question from here on out.)

Suppose $y \in [0,1]$ is rational. Then you can find a specific $z$ (in terms of $y$) for which we will get $f(z) = y$. What is it?
Now suppose $y \in [0,1]$ is irrational. Then you can find a different specific $z$ (in terms of $y$) for which we will get $f(z)=y$. What is it?

You will need a fact about rational and irrational numbers to make step 2 work, but as soon as you realize what that fact is, you should have no trouble proving it :)

Wow, I totally forgot what I learned in basic proofs class haha. Thank you for the comment!

If $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ then, choosing $z=y$ gives $f(z)=y$
If $y$ is irrational, then $z=1-y$ is irrational and
$$
f(z)=1-(1-y)=y
$$
